# Can I use had in sentence for future time? For example "We'd be fee." Is this a simple future or simple past?

Tags: sentence-construction, contractions, conditionals

Can I use had in sentence for future time?

For example **We'd be free**.

Is this a simple future or simple past?

Answer (score 2):

*We'd be free* would be understood to mean *We would be free*, which is the conditional tense. *We had be free* is not a valid sentence. You cannot use a verb form with *had* in the future tense.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make much sense. Closest correct form I can think of is "We had been free" which is past perfect.

I have seen had being used for future in this structure though: "I had better change that light bulb." which conveys some necessity in near future. More on it here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/had-better